# Node.js Shared memory

Tags: node.js, posix, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to find a way to send messages between processes using Shared Memory. The idea is to share large amounts of data between processes in an extremely fast way (TCP and ZeroMQ are too slow for this). Shared memory seems like a great way (POSIX/SystemV etc.). I have experience implementing in C++, but I cannot find anything for node.js. Are there any resources/examples?

My plan is to produce data in Julia which will be shared to Node, then node will do various things to it.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried redis? Or what do you mean with "TCP is too slow"? You can write a "shared buffer" in c/c++ and include it in your node.js app. I cant image a application where TCP would be to slow for IPC, so what are we talking about? (JS Atomics maybe?)

Comment: @Marc the key is, the OP wants to share "large amounts of data". Think e.g. of a video stream, where you could pre-allocate a shared memory segment to use for all frames. Sending such data over a pipe is considerably slower.